# Why do or should programmers save data in text based formats like JSON or XML instead of binary?

Tags: programming-practices, data, efficiency, storage

I see a lot of reasons to use binary over text-based formats.

- With binary, I find it a lot easier. I can use `fread(data, sizeof(struct DataStruct), 1, fileptr)` to read, or `fwrite` to write data. I find that a lot easier than finding and using someone else's bloated library to parse and encode data in JSON or XML.
- Since you're just reading the data directly, there is no parsing involved, making write and especially read operations a lot faster.
- Since it's binary, instead of text based, the files are a lot smaller.

However, despite all of that, text-based formats are widely used. Why are JSON, XML, OBJ models, and other text-based formats so popular? What other factors did I not consider that makes these inefficient text-based formats desirable?

Comment: Sure, it's easier until you want to move the binary file that you created on the Windows version of the app onto your phone so you can use the iOS version of the app while you are on the bus.  That might or might not work since I am pretty sure but not positive that iPhones are big-endian while Windows boxes are usually little-endian.  And if you want to do something the app doesn't do easily then an "export, edit and import" cycle is a very handy way to do almost everything.  Or, if you want to make sure people don't edit your files (like video game save files) then binary is the way to go.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah True, but what about always encoding integers as little endian and converting them to big endian on big endian platforms? By always byteswaping the numbers prior to saving, and after reading?

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363827/binary-data-formats-how-to-make-ensure-you-can-read-different-format-versions

Comment: The other thing to consider is what happens when you add even one member to your struct/object.  Now the files you write can't be read by the previous version and the files you already have can't be read by the new version.  With JSON/XML the previous version just ignores the items it doesn't know about and the new version can use a default for the missing fields.  You can do that with binary as well but then you have to keep both the new and old reead/write functions and embed a version number in the file.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I see, and that's a valid point. How I'd solve that problem is by making the first byte be a version ID used for parsing. Or, alternatively, how I solve that problem in my current projects is by always adding new fields to the end, so they wouldn't change the byte offset of existing fields.

Comment: @BlockofDiamond The idea of enforcing an encoding pattern (big or little) endian isn't new.  That was standardized for networking a long time ago and is not surprisingly  called "Network Byte Ordering"  See [Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking) in the Wikipedia article of Endianness.  There are standard library function calls in pretty well every language to do this.  There is also things like [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) for binary encoding of data in a predictable manner

Comment: Eric Raymond's book, *The Art of Unix Programming* has [a whole chapter](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/textualitychapter.html) on this. It's an excellent read.

Comment: @BlockofDiamond, once you add support for versioning to your binary file, you need a parser to consistently read the data and place it in the right elements of the data structure. Then the only advantage left for binary files is their smaller size.

Comment: In my view, if you need to find someone else's bloated library just for JSON conversion, then the problem is with your programming language.

Comment: @BlockofDiamond I think you're lacking some imagination here. Think of all the different dimensions two systems can differ in: floating point format, integer size, endianness, bit representations of booleans, struct member layout, preferred text encoding, etc. Various macros could add/remove entire chunks of members from a struct's declaration. Sure, you can add version flags, checks and conversions to make sure all doubles are 64 bit IEEE, to try to work it around it all, but what you're essentially doing is inventing your own shitty ad-hoc standard

Comment: Human readability.  Configuration files tend to be more and more written in JSON or YAML.

Comment: Why would `fread(data, sizeof(struct DataStruct), 1, fileptr)` be particularly more readable than `JsonConvert.Deserialize<DataStruct>(fileContent)` ? Also note that JSON serialization is included by default in .NET. Is your argument not just based on your own personal skill and experience, or the particular language you've chosen to use? Your assertions seem to argue that this is the case for everyone regardless of skill/language/experience, which is not the case.

Comment: @Flater Quite sure that `JsonConvert.Deserialize<DataStruct>(fileContent)` does not exist in C. But even if I was not using C, and that was part of the standard library of the language in question, the 2nd and 3rd arguments still apply. Just in that case, hidden behind the library function instead of in the developer's code.

Comment: @Alexander Why would a macro need to cut out entire chunks of struct members? What kind of user settings, document, or game file would be different on different platforms? I though it was good practice to aim for cross platform code. About big vs little endian, you have a point, but almost no common platforms are big endian anymore. About text encoding? Are there really platforms on which `'a' != 97`? Different systems have different floating point encodings? Examples?

Comment: @BlockofDiamond: I responded to your argument about _readability_. You working in C is not a valid argument against the use of text-based data formats in general - and you asked a general question here. _"Just in that case, hidden behind the library function instead of in the developer's code."_ At its very essence, this argues against the idea of incremental improvements made to code, whether it be frameworks, libraries, or additional abstraction. Just because you can ride a horse bareback and _you_ personally don't mind it, doesn't mean saddles are a waste of time for everyone else.

Comment: I though the readability argument was about the resulting file, not about the code that reads/writes it.

Comment: "C makes using libraries really hard, and doesn't have built in JSON support" is a pretty poor argument IMO. It's not our fault most C programmers like to reinvent the wheel with every program. Can't even complain, there's times when that's useful/warranted, but in every other programming sphere, people are trivially serializing/de-serializing data with ease.

Comment: @BlockofDiamond Do you really think there are no platforms where `'a' != 97`? Really?

Comment: @Alexander No, `'a' == 97` is standard ASCII, and if there was a platform that did not use ASCII, saving text would be a problem, and that would apply to text-based formats as well

Comment: The text encoding used in a text based format isn’t up for the writer to decide. It’s usually standardized. I won’t speak to “all text based formats”, but JSON for one *must* be encoded in [UTF-8 when passed between systems.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-8.1)  “The platform using x encoding” is very ambiguous. Typically that means it’s native string format is represented in memory by x encoding. If this is what you use as a serialization format, as you suggest, you’re screwed.

Comment: @Alexander Ok but seriously, what platforms _don't_ use ASCII/UTF-8?

Comment: “ No, 'a' == 97 is standard ASCII, and if there was a platform that did not use ASCII”, infamously, [`EBCDIC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is painfully incompatible with ASCII. It’s niche, but an embarrassingly large number of banks and big corporations are still running ancient cobol programs running on mainframes which use this encoding,p. But they can still interoperate with other Unicode systems, precisely because the exchange format isn’t their memory format, but is passed through a converter first.

Comment: @BlockofDiamond Neither Java, C#, nor JavaScript use UTF-8

Comment: @Alexander Probably an embarrassing question but what's the difference between UTF-8 and ASCII?

Comment: @Alexander Why don't these banks and big corporations get up to date?

Comment: It’s more than I can explain in a comment here. Read this first, and let me know if you have questions in the chat below https://medium.com/@apiltamang/unicode-utf-8-and-ascii-encodings-made-easy-5bfbe3a1c45a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119995/discussion-between-alexander-and-block-of-diamond).

Comment: BlockifDiamonds: ASCII supports 128 characters. Not even enough for proper English (Zoë is naïve), not enough for any Western language and totally unusable for the rest. Unicode supports _everything_. UTF8 is one of 5 common ways to encode Unicode, but that is a detail that is mostly invisible to the developer.

Comment: For a nice middle ground, check out https://capnproto.org/

Answer (score 11):

JSON and XML are less efficient than pure binary, but what you aren't considering is that they (JSON/XML, and some other formats like YAML) are standardised, while binary isn't - different systems, running in different environments or on different hardware, will encode what would be identical JSON or XML as non-identical binary.

That makes transmitting data between different systems less reliable and is a large factor in why JSON is a common format for data exchange in, say, HTTP requests. If you serialise data to a "plaintext"-like format its much easier to work with as a receiver.

Another consideration is also human readability, which may or may not be important depending on the field you work in, but being able to read and inspect stored data easily can help in debugging.

Comment: I see, but other than the endian of the systems in question, are there any examples of times when the binary wouldn't be identical?

Comment: supported/selected character sets and whether it uses null-terminating or specified length strings when dealing with text, what integer sizes are supported/used and how it might differentiate between them (might it try to parse 2 32bit numbers as a single 64bit one?), and ofcourse, big vs small endian. There may be others i'm not thinking of right now, but you only really need a few differences for it to be useful to standardise.

Comment: As for null-terminating or specified length strings, isn't that up to the coder, not the system? Whether I write the code to interpret data as null terminated vs specified length strings? Also couldn't they just use bitfields in `struct`s or fixed size integers such as `uint32_t`?

Comment: Systems where `int` is a different size from what you think it is. Systems with different padding conventions. Systems trying to read your C-written binary from Rust, Go, Java, (insert your least favourite language here).

Comment: it being "up to the coder" is part of why these things are transferred in a format like JSON in a standardised encoding (in my experience, usually utf8). you might choose to use null terminating strings and 32 bit ints, but if you need to send data to someone who uses specified lengths and/or 64 bit ints, you'd potentially have a problem. if you know for sure on both ends what the format would be, and speed/size is important, then yes, binary would be a good solution. Thats not always the case.

Comment: Struct padding: `__attribute__((packed))`

Comment: There are plenty of standardized binary message formats, ProtoBuf, Avro, MessagePack, etc... I think the win of JSON more lies in reduced complexity and increased readability. Or, maybe the tradeoffs are highly reliant on the use-case.

Comment: Thats true Jared, i was mostly referring to the original poster's mentioned preference of just basically reading/writing raw data of a struct with the expectation of it being in the correct format.

Answer (score 7):

- They're human readable: you can read and write them in plain text editor
- They're standardized: which means there are a wealth of off the shelf tooling available to work with them
- They're easy: you don't need to know whether your system is big or small endian, you don't need to know how strings are encoded in-memory in your language+platform combination (in-memory strings usually uses weird encoding like UTF-16/UTF-32 or some non standard extension of ASCII codepage because they are fixed width encoding, but these are wasteful for data storage/exchange which is almost always in UTF-8 as they produce smaller files), you don't need to know the memory alignment requirement of struct in your programming language+platform
- They're in standard libraries: most modern languages supports standard text based formats as part of their standard library, usually at least JSON and XML
- You can write schemas: schemas allows you to unambiguously specify what your file format should look like
- Schemas enable interoperability: if you're developing a file format that's used by multiple parties, a schema allows different parties to ensure that they're producing files that can be correctly read by all other implementations
- Schemas can automatically be turned into validating parsers: and into an API client library without you needing to write a single line of code yourself in the target platform
- They're more secure: especially if you have a schema/validating parser, there's much less chance of getting data that you don't expect and causing security issues like buffer overflow, arbitrary code execution, etc. The history book is full of issues caused by poorly specified binary file format causing security issues, these issues are nearly non existent when you use text-based format.
- Speed and size is usually of minimal concern for data interchange: your bottleneck is going to be the network, not file parsing. Once you downloaded the data, you can extract the data and store the important bits in a database, indexed and in a form that you can work with efficiently in the local system
- They're plain text: so Unix tools knows how to work with them to some degree, you can use grep and sed to search and script one off manipulations easily

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this question is posed more as rhetoric than from genuine puzzlement.

First off it must be acknowledged that binary formats are long-established and a perfectly legitimate option for saving data.

Though probably not what you had in mind, image formats are an obvious example where binary remains king - there is no breakdown of image data into human-readable scan lines or other algorithmic elements.

But equally, text-based formats were also long-established before XML and JSON became popular, particularly CSV for tabular data, and for example INI files (on Windows) for application configuration.

The primary advantage of binary formats for bulk data in the past was that they were compact (mainly because there are often no delimiters between fields, or other metadata - structural and descriptive information is stored almost entirely in the application or source code), and they are fast to parse because they are well-integrated with the application which uses them. The application is essentially written as a custom parser, probably exploiting assumptions built into the language or platform.

However speed and size for file formats and file-based applications have receded as concerns nowadays. What tends to be more important is durability and flexibility.

More standardised representations of data, more standardised layouts, the storage of descriptive metadata alongside the data, these are all recognised as things which tend to preserve the ability to read and write the data in the long-term, and ease the ability of programmers to read and manipulate the data without access to (or detailed familiarity with) the original source code or development environment.

Indeed, as other answers say, they can also be a boon for debugging and manual data recovery.

Comment: "Though probably not what you had in mind, image formats are an obvious example where binary remains king" except for when it comes to formats like SVG, of course!

Comment: @Jasmijn: or netpbm images, but that probably fails the "widely used" criteria.

Comment: @Jasmijn, exactly so! I was thinking of photographics as opposed to vector graphics, but the print and publishing industry has a long history of standardised file formats with extensive metadata, mainly because their operational scale has never allowed them the luxury of assuming that their data will be handled end-to-end by one dedicated application on one piece of hardware, and indexed and organised casually by a small number of users.

Answer (score 4):

I should add a very pertinent war story.
Way back in time Borland released Delphi 1.0 with the screen design files saved in binary format. This was a minor disaster.

- Delphi was not itself bug free. It would regularly corrupt the file. It helped if you had backups or a very understanding boss.
- Delphi supported third party libraries that could add to the layout file. This probably meant that that corruption could happen over which Borland had little control.
- Renaming a screen component or changing it's class was a pain. All you could do was delete the component, add the replacement and wire up all the properties again. Refactoring was heavily impacted.

To their credit, Borland fixed all this by changing the layout file to a text file  (I think) xml and all those problems went away.

Ever since, I have stuck with text files.

Answer (score 3):

You also miss a important point: Not all of us are using C/C++.

In other languages (like Java, JavaScript, ...) you can't easily save or read a struct.
And if you want to share these files between programs with different languages, than you need a standardized format.

In JavaScript or Java it's very hard (or almost impossible) to read a not aligned (packed) struct, saved by C. Because they don't working with bits and bytes. Java-Devs have not to worry about endian, 32 vs. 64bit, aligned/packed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious advantages that text is human readable, sometimes human fixable, and sometimes diffable, independent of endianness, and fully Unicode compatible:

1. Specifically for JSON, in the environments that I use I can translate a file or a byte array containing JSON into a generic data structure containing arrays, dictionaries, and various primitives, with a single call. The integrity of the JSON data will be checked. And I don't need to know anything about the contents for this. So I have a single checkpoint where I know either "all my data is valid JSON" or "my data is not valid JSON".
2. JSON describes its contents. That makes it relatively easy to read data from older or newer versions of your software with a bit of effort. With home-made binary data this is hard.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good answers already but I just wanted to mention some important bits that are lacking in many answers.

- Size is not a problem in many JSON protocols also because it is or can be zipped on the fly, either it fits on a couple of IP packet so there is zero gain on saving some spare bytes (that's the case for most JSON protocols) either you ship large data and you can gain ~80% of the original size if you just zip it.
- Some binary standardized protocols exist, sometimes for storage, sometimes for efficient unpacking compared to zipped JSON(although that's quite fast). There is life outside JSON and XML. Check for example MesssagePack or BSON.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you're using C or C++ here.  In that case, here's my cautionary tale.

Twenty-odd years ago, someone [else!] wrote an Application in [MFC] C++ and used *exactly* this technique to save files from that Application.  Only that Application ever needed to use these files, so that was fine.
This application was *hugely* successful.

Fast-forward twenty years:

- Users have saved away tens of thousands of files from this Application.
- The technology is seen as "old" and "obsolete".
- Very few people are left who know how to work with it and *even less* want to get their hands dirty looking after this "ancient monstrosity".
- Management would *love* to replace the application with something else ...
  ... but what about *all those binary files* that the Users have saved away and *still rely on* to run their business?

Someone is going to have [re-]invent a way to read those file into some *other* Application.

How much easier (less expensive and less *Risky*) would this exercise be *if only* the original Developer had put in the time and effort to save the data in a more *portable* format ...

Answer (score 0):

The other reason (I guess) is that XML/JSON are human readable. It sometimes matters. For example JSON is widely used as a configuration file format so it is *supposed* to be written/edited by humans. Your question  kinda sounds like "why there's a hammer if there's a shovel" ;) Binary and non-binary formats are created for different purposes. As other people mentioned here not every one uses C/C++ (e.g. me). It is much simpler to work with XML/JSON using Python than binary (without a standard).

Python parse/load JSON:

```
import json
parsed = json.loads(string_json)
```

> With binary, I find it a lot easier. I can use `fread(data, sizeof(struct DataStruct), 1, fileptr)` to read, or `fwrite` to write data. I find that a lot easier than finding and using someone else's bloated library to parse and encode data in JSON or XML.

In some other languages these libraries are widely used. There's no need to do parsing "manually" in Python for example.

> Since you're just reading the data directly, there is no parsing involved, making write and especially read operations a lot faster.

Reading by a machine: yes. By a human: no. No human can get it at all.

> Since it's binary, instead of text based, the files are a lot smaller.

Smaller: yes. Human readable: no. You can't understand a binary file without an auxiliary program. You won't save config in a binary file, yeah? ;)

So sometimes you need a binary file. Sometimes you need a text file. Your C++ code is a text file so you can read and write it being a human. But it is compiled to machine code in order to be ran more easily and fast by a machine.

Comment: I see the analogy that JSON and XML is like uncompiled binary

Answer (score 0):

## Efficient... How?

There are many ways for something to be efficient:

- Total Storage used
- Speed of reading
- complexity of code performing the reading
- adding new fields
- removing old fields
- saving a different length string/blob
- network communication
- error detection/correction
- ease of implementation by other programmers

and more to boot...

## Text is Binary

Unless my understanding of how computers work is fundamentally flawed, text files are binary files.

What you have is a much more nuanced world:

- Some Files contain fixed length data-structures repeated one after another: Record based Files
- Some files contain variable length blocks whose contents are sometimes different to the previous or next block, but form a chain of blocks: Block based Files
- Some files contain data in some form of graph with records pointing to where related data is within the file: Structure based Files
- Some files contain self describing data which follows a minimum set of conventions: Formal Language based Files
- Some files contain semi-structured data which is generally freeform with a few areas of formality to ease automated processing: Natural Language based Files

And then there are the files that nest different sorts of file within demarked regions. eg: a record based file may nest a structured file within it logically. A Block based file may have blocks whose contents are Formal Language based.

Needless to say it doesn't make a lot of sense to talk about text files without knowing what kind of text file it is. It being human ledgable without a piece of paper and a calculator is neither here nor there.

They could be:

- Natural Language based: like an SMTP file.
- Formal Language based: like JSON or XML
- Block Based: Like some variants of Key Value Pair or CSV
- Record Based: Like some variants of CSV or Key Value Pair

Comment: Text ist not binary. Binary-files are not human-readble (you need a hex-editor to read or edit them). But text-files can be read by humans.

Comment: @akop At the file level all data is simply a collection of bits - thus all files are binary.  What you call a "text file" is simply your tool of choice taking those bits and mapping them to glyphs that you are able to interpret as text.  And the mapping function is not universal, EG EBCDIC and ASCII encoded files are totally different.

Comment: @PeterM if this definition is true, than are all files binary. But luckily is this not the case. Files are human readable, when a normal encoder can transform the bits and bytes to ASCII (or familiar). On the other side: A executable (as example) does not contains any human-readble bytes. You can't type `cat file.exe` to look what the program do.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039050/difference-between-text-file-and-binary-file for more infos.

Comment: @akop Your "cat" example is false equivalence.  Look at how a character is displayed on  a screen: 1. A binary value is read from a file.  2. That value is used as an index into a font file that points to the glyph data.  3. The glyph data is rendered into the display buffer via a graphical process.   4. Your brain recognizes the image in the display buffer as a character.     This process is the same whether you use "cat" or "hexdump" to display the contents of a file - only the mapping of the binary data to the glyph changes.

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing to do with the definiton of a 'binary file'. Look the discussion in my link, google it or have a look to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Comment: @akop which is why i pointed out that it is actually more nuanced than that. Record orientated, block orientated, semi-structured, etc... The efficiency of each is directly proportional to its usage. Record is horrendous for variant data, unstructured is hard for automating meaningfully.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned benefits are moot.

- In any scenario where text based files are used, performance is not
  an issue.
- Easy access on the programmer level should not be an issue,
  you would be talking to an object model rather than mess will low
  level persistency logic. Persistency should be encapsulated anyway,
  no matter how it is implemented.

Text based formats provide structure. They are human readable and writable using standard editing tools. Mind that it is often not just you, the programmer, who needs to deal with those files. "This is easy for me" hardly ever cuts it in software development. I could have answered you in Dutch because that would have been easy for me but it probably would not have been very helpful.

Comment: Um... no, parsing is a step, even if it's hidden behind JSON library functions in high level languages

Comment: @Block of Diamond It is a step, no argument there. What is your point?

Comment: Each extra step will mean that it will take more time, so I disagree that my mentioned benefits are invalid

Comment: My software often exchanges data in heavily encrypted JSON. The encryption is needed. The time for parsing JSON is tiny compared to the crypto. producing and parsing JSON is done with standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather simple: you should use text when interoperability with tools that are known to require text or where you know you will be operating with other tools and you don’t of a shared non-text format.

If you want to have an image that is going to edited or analyzed by other tools, you’ll choose a binary format best represents your needs. You know what format you want and what tools can support it. If on the other hand you have a bunch of non-image, but non-text data that can be represented as text, and you want to let other tools deal with it, you’ll use a textual format that allows them to extract the data and examine it.

Simple example, a sql database table with a json or xml column.  The database understands various base binary types: dates, times, numbers, even binary data, but if you want to query the last, you have to decode it yourself.  It’s extremely difficult to find a row based upon partial binary content, particularly if the data is in a variable format.  On the other hand, even if the sql engine doesn’t allow decoding of the textual format into a more binary format, it can still be queried  as raw text.  Finding rows with Zarg: 37 will be possible.

And of course the same thing applies if you’re not using a database to store the data: if you want a sum of zargs (whatever that may be) you don’t need to understand the rest of the format.

Also, having had to reverse engineer a couple of file formats in the past, I can say it would have been a lot easier if the native format hadn’t been binary. Not that I think it would have been logical for them to do so, but having an export to a textual representations would have been terrific.